# Small black spot on sourdough starter

Tags: baking, food-safety, sourdough

I haven't fed my sourdough in about a month so I was going to feed it and I saw a black spot on the dough. I scooped it out and fed the sourdough.I'm worried if this could possibly be black mold and if so is it still safe to eat because i did get rid of the black spot and whatever i use it for will be cooked, or is it just completely contaminated.

Comment: It's hard to say without a close up picture or better description.  A "black spot" could really be anything. I would say, if you are concerned, start over.

Answer (score 3):

Molds themselves are usually killed by heat treatment, but the toxins they've produced are not. Depending on the water content, it's probable that there's residual mycelium and toxins in the starter even after removing the spot.

I'd say throw away and start over if you do suspect that it was a black mold.

Answer (score 0):

the black spot is probably mold. mold is toxic and not recommended to be consumed. it is a strong poison and affects people badly. even if you remove the mold, the toxins produced by the song remain in the other product. best remove the starter and throw it. and make a new starter.In addition, the fly inhibits the development process in the starter culture. the starter culture itself stops its development microorganisms change their development in starter culture. starter culture can not fulfill its mission to ferment bread and convey specific flavor.